# Redux how to set values of payloads according to the index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have textfields for 5 rows (each row having textfields of same name as it is iterated for 5 times) and i want to do validation that the textfield should not be empty and and i'm using redux for generationg that error. But If i click on one of the textbox and left it empty, all the 5 textboxes are showing error.

**Form**
const ItemInfo = ({
errors, // errors generated from redux getting from parent Component
classes,
index,
getItem,
validateInput,
}) => {
const [item, handleItem] = React.useState({});

```
  const [err, setErr] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (errors) setErr(errors);
  }, [errors]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const { rate, quantity, discount } = item;
    if (item.item && rate && quantity && discount) {
      //Send item details to parent PurchaseForm
      //console.log(index, item);
      getItem(item);
    }
  }, [item]);

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    handleItem((items) => ({
      ...items,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <tr xs={12}>
      <td>{index}</td>
      <td>
        <TextField
          id="item"
          name="item"
          type="item"
          className={classes.itemField}
          helperText={err.item}
          error={err.item ? true : false}
          value={item.item || ""}
          onChange={(event) => handleInput(event)}
          onBlur={(e) => validateInput(e)}
          onFocus={(e) => removeError(e)}
          fullWidth
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        // Similarly other form components
      </td>
      <td>
        <Button color="red" onClick={() => delItem()}>
          &times;
        </Button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ItemInfo);
```

**Reducer**

```
import {
  SET_ERRORS,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
  SET_AUTHENTICATED,
  LOADING,
} from "./types";

const initialState = {
  authenticated: false,
  loading: false,
  errors: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_AUTHENTICATED:
      return {
        ...state,
        authenticated: action.payload,
      };
    case LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload,
        errors: null,
      };
    case SET_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errors: action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errors: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Difficulty I'm facing**

[image]

Please suggest me how to design reducer such that error appears only on the textbox where it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i got the way to get the desired output. I maintained an array of error in redux state and store the error according to the index of the row and then showing the error of particular index of the row.